# Aurelia-dialog close on Escape key

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying the aurelia-dialog plugin but want it to look/behave much more like Bootstrap Modal.  One simple difference is that aurelia-dialog does not close when I press the Escape key.  Without getting hacky and adding keyboard listeners, is there an easy way to activate the Escape key to close Aurelia-modal?

Here's a snippet of code to show how it's being instantiated:

```
this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: SettingsSchoolDivisionEdit, model: record }).then(response => {
  if (!response.wasCancelled) {
    console.log("Success");
  }
});
```

Comment: Dialogs absolutely close on cancel as noted in the readme

Comment: This is not a helpful response... my aurelia-dialog is not closing when I press Escape.

Comment: you've not provided any code samples so not sure how to help

Comment: I just added the instantiation.  However, I'm wondering whether this is a limitation of the aurelia-dialog plugin.

Comment: As the primary maintainer of that plugin I can assure it's not a limitation - the esc key works and can be seen in action in the sample app in the dialog repo, if you pull it down and run it.  If you are locking your dialogs then they would not be closable of course, else they should close with the code you have shown.

Comment: Thanks so much, and sorry -- I didn't realize you were responding from an authoritative stance.  I learned that the lock property is set to true by default and that it prevents the Escape key from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that the lock property is set to true by default and that it prevents the Escape key from working.  To allow the Escape key to work, add `lock: false` to the instantiation like this:

```
this.dialogService.open({ viewModel: SettingsSchoolDivisionEdit, model: record, lock: false }).then(response => {
  if (!response.wasCancelled) {
    console.log("Success");
  }
});
```